# Testing classifier with binomial test when group sizes are unequal

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, svm, binomial-distribution, unbalanced-classes

I have data from 50 human subjects, who are divided into groups A and B (30 participants are in group A and 20 participants in group B). I also have a range of measurements from each subject. I have used a machine learning algorithm (SVM) to predict the subject groups from the features using leave-one-out cross-validation.

I would like to have a p-value for my classifier. If I have understood correctly, I can treat each prediction as a Bernoulli trial, and test for significance using a binomial test. However, I'm a little confused about the details. The paper ([pdf](http://www.princeton.edu/~matthewb/Publications/PereiraBotvinick10.pdf)) I was following, in the section 'result significance', assumes that the subject groups are of equal size. That's not the case here. What do I need to do to make the test work?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your reference (link is broken) is doing a hypothesis test for if their classification accuracy is higher than $50\%$, as a naïve model should be able to get half of the classifications right (just guess one class every time).

For your problem, a naïve model should be able to predict the correct outcome $60\%$ of the time by predicting the majority class every time. Therefore, the hypothesis test would not be if your model achieves an accuracy above $50\%$ but above $60\%$. It sounds like your link would would have proposed a one-sided, one-sample proportion test for your model proportion classified correctly (accuracy as a proportion (e.g., $0.8$ instead of $80\%$)). Call your proportion classified correctly as $p$.

$$
H_0: p = 0.6\\
H_a: p > 0.6
$$

A z-test might be the most straightforward way to do this. Example S.6.2 at the Penn State University link [here](https://online.stat.psu.edu/statprogram/reviews/statistical-concepts/proportions) gives an example.

Classification accuracy has its issues [[1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312780/why-is-accuracy-not-the-best-measure-for-assessing-classification-models), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/603663/academic-reference-on-the-drawbacks-of-accuracy-f1-score-sensitivity-and-or-sp)], but if you insist on using it, comparing to the accuracy of a model that always predicts the majority category seems like the reasonable baseline. My answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/595958/247274) gives a justification for this (and another answer to that question gives a reasonable explanation for why a different baseline might be reasonable, under the assumption that classification accuracy is not quite the right measure of model performance).